# SQL to Query the db and return all posts and it's metas

Tags: query, sql

I am trying to query the wp db and return all posts and it's metas.
However, the return is very slow. Am I doing it the right way to get the most optimal results?

Please see my SQL below:

```
SELECT CONCAT('<a href="',p.post_title,'">',p.post_title,'</a>') AS 'Projects Title', 
customer_username.meta_value AS 'wc_customer_username',
service_count.meta_value AS 'wc_service_count',
item_count.meta_value AS 'wc_item_count',
addon_count.meta_value AS 'wc_addon_count',
total.meta_value AS 'wc_total',
method_title.meta_value AS 'wc_method_title',
order_created.meta_value AS 'wc_order_created',
menu_order.meta_value AS 'Menu Order', 
levels.meta_value AS 'Levels'
FROM wp_posts AS p
JOIN wp_postmeta AS customer_username
  ON customer_username.post_id = p.ID 
JOIN wp_postmeta AS service_count
  ON service_count.post_id = p.ID 
JOIN wp_postmeta AS item_count
  ON item_count.post_id = p.ID 
JOIN wp_postmeta AS addon_count
  ON addon_count.post_id = p.ID 
JOIN wp_postmeta AS total
  ON total.post_id = p.ID 
JOIN wp_postmeta AS method_title
  ON method_title.post_id = p.ID
JOIN wp_postmeta AS order_created
  ON order_created.post_id = p.ID
JOIN wp_postmeta AS menu_order
  ON menu_order.post_id = p.ID
JOIN wp_postmeta AS levels
  ON levels.post_id = p.ID  
WHERE 1=1 
AND customer_username.meta_key = 'wc_customer_username'
AND service_count.meta_key = 'wc_service_count'
AND item_count.meta_key = 'wc_item_count'
AND addon_count.meta_key = 'wc_addon_count'
AND total.meta_key = 'wc_total'
AND method_title.meta_key = 'wc_method_title'
AND order_created.meta_key = 'wc_order_created'
AND menu_order.meta_key = 'wc_menu_order' 
AND levels.meta_key = 'wc_level' 
AND p.post_type = 'projects' AND levels.meta_value = '0'
ORDER BY menu_order.meta_key = 'wc_menu_order'
```

Comment: How many posts do you have? This is an incredibly expensive query. Have you tried limiting the number of results? Why do you need to retrieve them with an SQL query like this?

Comment: Well. It is mainly the custom metas of the post I am after. I need the query to build a custom datatable to show in the template.